# Getting exception backtrace and output in Rexster console

Tags: groovy, titan, rexster

I have a setup with Titan 0.5.2 running with Rexster. When I use the rexster console to run some code on the Titan side and exception happens, I get only short message like:

> ==>An error occurred while processing the script for language [groovy]. All transactions   across all graphs in the session have
>   been concluded with failure: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException:
>   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: a for class:
>   Script8

And no output from the script (that is produced with println or such) is visible. Is it possible to make the rexster console produce the exception backtraces (e.g. like Titan's gremlin console does) and see the output from the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get much more out of Rexster Console.  If you look at server logs for Rexster though, you should see a bit more output.  Of course, I wouldn't expect the trace to tell you too much more in the specific case of a "No such property" type of error.